# How many active skills on average do classes use in Titan Quest?

Tags: android, mobile, titan-quest

I recently purchased Titan Quest on my phone (it's the base game with no expansion masteries) and I was wondering which builds are most affected by mobile gaming. The mobile version has 8 slots for active skills (buffs/attacks) and a standard attack, which I believe can be replaced with another melee skill (so possibly 9 slots). How many active skills do builds typically use? Or more specifically, are there any builds that require cycling between more than 8/9 skills often?

Comment: Can't tell for mobile version, but on PC you mostly choose one skill and maximize it. Sometimes two (e.g. one for single target and other is aoe). You won't get enough skill points to maximize everything thus 8 slots should be enough if that's the reason of the question.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes not having enough slots to use all the skills efficiently was my concern. If you post that as an answer and give an example of skill point allocation for a typical build I'll choose you as best answer.